# Drupal 6 does not like it when an image tag's absolute path contains “http:”

Tags: media

I'm using Drupal 6.28 and there's something i don't understand.

i have a page that contains an image tag pointing to an absolute path. e.g.

```
<img alt="google logo" src="http://www.google.com.sg/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height:190px; width:538px" />
```

when the content is saved, drupal returns a "Page Not Found" error.

i found out that if i remove the "http:" at the start of the src attribute, there wouldn't be any problem. everything would be ok. i.e.

```
<img alt="google logo" src="//www.google.com.sg/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height:190px; width:538px" />
```

is there some setting that i may have messed up that causes this?

Thanks

Comment: Strangeness with saving aside, you really shouldn't be hotlinking images like that.

Comment: Just check if there is any text filtering happening. You should find it in text formatting settigns.

Comment: thanks for the replies. i tried turning off the text filters, but this didn't help.

Comment: What modules do you have installed on your site?

Comment: hi, @hargobind
i have the following modules installed and enabled:
CiviCRM, Core - Color, Database Logging, Help, Menu, Path, Taxonomy, Update Status, 
Elysia Cron,
Login Security,
CKEditor,
Webform

One additional information that i missed to point out is that drupal is installed on a subdomain.
e.g. sub1.mydomain.com
not sure if this matters.


Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any specific ideas as to why this is happening. Perhaps check the DB log or your webserver's error log to see if it shows you any clues. You can also try disabling each module and seeing if that has an effect -- none of the Core modules should be an issue, so try the other ones. Good luck.

Comment: Hello. Things like lists of modules should go directly into a questions. Comments can be purged once and then and nobody will really care ;) so please edit your question. Also, when you get 404, can you provide a path you are directed to, and excerpt from watchdog and server's error.log?

Answer (score 1):

the issue i reported was caused by a mod_security setting.
my host fixed it after i spoke to them.

Comment: Good to know. Could you make them to tell you what they changed? And then share this with us?

Comment: hi guys, it turns out that it was caused by some mod_security setting by my host. when i asked them what they changed to fix it, all they said was that they white listed something.